# Java/JavaME: Quicker geometric vector addition

Tags: java, vector, geometry, addition

I'm making a simple Vector class with a simple usage, so I don't want to import a whole library (like JScience...) for something that I can do myself.

Currently I have made this code so far:

```
public void add(Vector2D v){
    double ang = this.angle*Math.PI/180;
    double mag = this.magnitude;
    double ang0 = v.angle*Math.PI/180;
    double mag0 = v.magnitude;
    //vector to coordinates
    double x1 = mag*Math.cos(ang);
    double y1 =-mag*Math.sin(ang);
    //adding the other vector's coordinates
    double x2 =x1+mag*Math.cos(ang0);
    double y2 =y1-mag*Math.sin(ang0);
    //back to vector form
    double newMagnitude = Math.sqrt(x2*x2+y2*y2);
    double newAngle = Math.atan2(y2,x2);
    this.magnitude = newMagnitude;
    this.angle = newAngle;

}
```

It's converting both vectors to coordinates and then back with the trigonometric functions, But those are extremely slow, and the method will be used very frequently.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Store the vectors in cartesian coordinates instead of converting back and forth? That's the normal way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, some terminology 101:

**Point:** a dimensionless entity that a space is made of.

**Space:** a set of points.

**Euclidean space:** a set of points, together with a set of lines and with the notion of closeness (topology). The set of lines is bound by the Euclid's axioms. It is uniquely defined by its dimension.

**Vector:** a translation-invariant relationship between two points in an Euclidean space.

**Coordinate system:** a mapping from tuples of real numbers to points or vectors in some space.

**Cartesian coordinate system:** A specific mapping, with the properties (in case of the Euclidean 2D space) that the set of points `ax+by+c=0` is a line unless `a,b` are both zero, that the vectors `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` are perpendicular and unit length, and that points in space are close together iff they are close together in all coordinates. This is what you refer to as "coordinates".

**Polar coordinate system:** Another specific mapping, that can be defined from the cartesian coordinates: `[arg,mag]` in polar coordinates map to `[cos(arg)*mag, sin(arg)*mag]` in cartesian coordinates. This is what you refer to as "vector form".

---

The cartesian coordinate system has multiple benefits over the polar coordinate system. One of them is easier addition: `[x1,y1]+[x2,y2]=[x1+x2,y1+y2]` and scalar multiplication: `[x1,y1].[x2,y2]=x1*x2+y1*y2`. Additive inversion is slightly easier as well: `-[x,y]=[-x,-y]`

Another benefit is that while polar coordinates are strictly 2D (there is no unique extension - the spherical coordinate system is a candidate, though), cartesian coordinates extend naturally to any number of dimensions.

For this reason, it is beneficial - and usual - to always store vectors in their cartesian coordinate form.

If you ever need vectors in their polar form, then (and only then) convert, once and for all.

Polar coordinates not as useful. They can be used for input and output, but they are rarely useful for computation.

---

You keep storing your vectors in the polar form. You convert them to their cartesian form for computation, then convert back to polar - only to convert them to the cartesian again.

You should store your vectors in the cartesian form. The performance improvement should be clearly visible if you drop the redundant conversion.

Even if you want to rotate a vector, it's not beneficial to convert to polar and back. Rotation by a signed angle `a` is as easy as `[x*cos(a)+y*sin(a), y*cos(a)-x*sin(a)]`. That's *two* trigonometric functions (at most - you can cache these values) to rotate an entire array of vectors.